# Convertir una cadena de texto en un array de enteros (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una duda, necesito crear una JavaScript que cuando el usuario clickee en un boton tomara el texto escrito previamente en una caja de texto y se convertira en un arreglo de numeros y se mostrara en otra caja de texto el numero mayor. Ejemplo: en la caja de texto #1 ingreso los sig numeros 1,5,8,10,15 y al presionar el boton se mostrara en la caja de texto #2 el numero mayor que seria 15
Mi codigo es este

```
<script>
    function btnDeterminarMayor() {
        var a = document.getElementById("txtNumeros");
        var arreglo = a.split(",");
        var mayor = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] > mayor) {
                mayor = a[i];
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("txtNumeroMayor").value = mayor;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes convertir rápidamente una serie de números, separados por comas, en un array usando JSON.parse:

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', buscaMaximo);

function buscaMaximo() {
  let datos = document.getElementById('numeros').value;
  let array = JSON.parse(`[${datos}]`);
  let resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
  resultado.innerHTML=`El mayor es ${Math.max.apply(this, array)}`;
}
```

```html
<input id="numeros"/>
<button id="btn">Buscar máximo</button>
<p id="resultado"> </p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Al comparar debes hacerlo en Enteros y usar el arreglo que preparaste

```
<script>
    function btnDeterminarMayor() {
        var a = document.getElementById("txtNumeros");
        var arreglo = a.split(",");
        var mayor = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
            if (parseInt(arreglo[i]) > mayor ) {
                mayor = parseInt( arreglo[i] );
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("txtNumeroMayor").value = mayor;
    }
</script>
```